# How to use LINQ to SQL and DevExpress grid by implementing Extensibility Method Definitions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, devexpress

Using ASP.NET MVC, I've used the designer to create a Product class, and display it in the DevExpress grid.

When saving changes in the grid, the following method works:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProductGridPartialUpdate([ModelBinder(typeof(DevExpressEditorsBinder))] Product prod)
    {
        var EditProd = db.Products.Single(p => p.Id == prod.Id);
        if (EditProd != null)
        {
            EditProd.ProductCode = prod.ProductCode;
            EditProd.ProductTitle = prod.ProductTitle;
            EditProd.BinNo = prod.BinNo;
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }

        var q = from p in db.Products select p;
        return PartialView("ProductGridPartial", q);
    }
```

But from what I've been reading, I was thinking it would work more like the following:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProductGridPartialUpdate([ModelBinder(typeof(DevExpressEditorsBinder))] Product prod)
    {
        db.UpdateProduct(prod);

        var q = from p in db.Products select p;
        return PartialView("ProductGridPartial", q);
    }
```

Or:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProductGridPartialUpdate([ModelBinder(typeof(DevExpressEditorsBinder))] Product prod)
    {
        db.SubmitChanges();

        var q = from p in db.Products select p;
        return PartialView("ProductGridPartial", q);
    }
```

Is my method the "correct" way to do it, or is there some conventional way to make the two examples work? I see in the auto-generated designer file, it's got the following chunk of code:

```
#region Extensibility Method Definitions
partial void OnCreated();
partial void InsertProduct(Product instance);
partial void UpdateProduct(Product instance);
partial void DeleteProduct(Product instance);
#endregion
```

But when I'm not sure what needs to be inside the partial UpdateProduct method, and when I added the following code in a new file, then called db.UpdateProduct(prod), I get the error: "is inaccessible due to its protection level". The code I tried was:

```
namespace TradeMeStore.Models
{
    partial class TradeMeStoreDataContext
    {
        partial void UpdateProduct(Product instance)
        {
            ExecuteDynamicUpdate(instance);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first approach is more preferable. It is a common logic for CRUD operation(s):

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

- Create a DataContext instance;
- Retrieve the edited DataItem;
- Edit the DataItem properties;
- Submit Changes.

If you wish to implement a custom CRUD functionality, you should worry about data-integrity yourself.

> is inaccessible due to its protection level

Mark both the “TradeMeStoreDataContext” class and “UpdateProduct” method as public.

Comment: ok, so my current approach is the most preferable. This means I won't need to implement the UpdateProduct partial method? What's a situation where I should implement the UpdateProduct method then? I'm wondering what the intended purpose of those Extensibility Method Definitions are.

Comment: Also, should I be creating a local DataContext inside each method or is it sufficient to create it once as an instance variable in the controller, then each method references that?